# Java Cannot find symbol Syntax error

Tags: java

I am new to java and I a have written the code below.  For some reason I'm getting `Cannot find symbol   symbol: Method size()   location:  class Object`  error message.  I have read it is a common syntax error, but I cannot figure out where I went wrong. Please advise!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BillboardMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Billboard billboard = new Billboard();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("******** Billboard Menu********");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please select a billboard message from the menu ");

            for (int i = 0; i < billboard.getMessages.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ": " + billboard.getMessages().get(i));
            }
            System.out.println(billboard.getMessages().size()+1 + ": Add new message.");
            System.out.println((billboard.getMessages().size() + 2) + ": Show  current text.");
            System.out.println((billboard.getMessages().size() + 3) + ": Exit.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            int code = console.nextInt();

            if (code == billboard.getMessages().size()+1) {
                System.out.print("Enter new text here: ");
                String newText = console.next();
                billboard.addNewText(newText);
                System.out.println("The new text has been set to billboard");
            } else if (code == billboard.getMessages().size() + 2) {
                System.out.println("Current text is: " + billboard.getText());

            } else if (code == billboard.getMessages().size() + 3) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                billboard.setText(code);
                System.out.println("The text has been set to billboard.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `getMessages` to `getMessages()`;

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < billboard.getMessages.size(); i++) {}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < billboard.getMessages().size(); i++) {}
```

As you have done in:

```
System.out.println(billboard.getMessages().size()+1 + ": Add new message.");
```

**Edit**

- If your `messages` variable is `String` or related Object type use `billboard.getMessages().length()`
- If your `messages` variable is `List<String>` or any other Collection Object type use
  `billboard.getMessages().size()`
- If your `messages` variable is `Array Type` `E.g. int[],String[],etc` use
  `billboard.getMessages().length`

Comment: Thank you, I made the change, but the error still exists.  The size() seems to be the issue as it is underlined in red and the error appears only in the lines where  size()  is written.

Comment: what is variable type for `messages`?

Comment: I don't understand, because my variable is List<String>, so it should be working, but it is not.

Comment: Cannot find symbol    symbol:  method size()    location  Class object

Comment: can you show the declaration of your variable and check whether it has proper getter/setter method?

Comment: public class Billboard {
    private String text;
    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();